# MavensMate package subscription?

Tags: mavensmate

In Eclipse, you can create a new project based on package name and it will bring in all of the metadata included in the package.  Does MavensMate offer the same type of feature?  I only see the specific metadata object types I can subscribe to individually, but nothing that lets me define a package name to pull from.